# A word that means that a germ or disease can affect a species

Tags: single-word-requests

I swear I've read a sentence like "Mosquitoes don't die of the diseases they transmit because those germs are not _____ to mosquitoes" or "Dragons' mouths aren't really clean, but they're generally not harmful to humans because the germs in a dragon's mouth are not _____ to humans".

Does this word exist?

Comment: This is off the topic, but I question the quote that the germs in a dog's mouth are innocuous to humans.  I know first hand that the germs in a cat's mouth can rapidly cause severe infection to humans if the skin is broken.

Comment: @ab2: They won't in most cases, 'cos germs/parasites are normally *very* host-specific, so the bugs that like to live in a cat's mouth aren't usually equipped to survive in a *human* body. Which is just as well, or we'd prolly all be dead of swine or bird flu by now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - As someone who's treated many, many, many infections including dog and cat bites, I have to wonder where you're getting that crazy idea. Look up Pasturella, for crying out loud. If you don't treat a cat bite, that's really poor medicine, and more likely than not, you'll end up hospitalizing the person.

Comment: @medica: You're in the profession, so obviously you see the (relatively low) number of cases where the pet's bit does in fact lead to an infection. It's still the case that most such *bites* don't become infected (and certainly not most of the different *kinds* of cat-mouth-bacteria, which is what I had in mind). And you yourself know as well as I do, (if not better, because of your job) that host specificity is a very relevant factor here - as illustrated by the swine/bird flu point.

Comment: FumbleFingers and medica:  I am sorry I started this.  Can we agree that FF is right about many kinds of cat-mouth bacteria and that medica and I are right about the specific kind of bacteria (bacterium ?) which causes a very nasty infection if the wound is not promptly and thoroughly cleaned, as most sensible people do when bitten?  (And also about the rare possibility of the rabies virus ?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Sorry, but you are not a doctor, and in the case of cat bites, about 70% of which get infected, you don't know what you're talking about. People come in when they've been bitten, not only when they become infected. This is the point *I* was addressing. Your statement is preposterous. [Here, read this. It's not technical.](https://www.minnpost.com/second-opinion/2014/02/cat-bites-hand-can-cause-serious-infections-mayo-study-finds)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - P.S. It's not just the bites to the hand that get infected; they just happen to be more serious because they enter deep spaces. Every significant (clear puncture wound) cat bit should be treated.

Comment: @ab2: Let's not get too hung up about this. I was after all primarily responding to the ***dog*** bite scenario in the question, and as I'm sure we here are aware, it really *is* true that people in general tend to think they're more serious (not least because dogs have very powerful jaws, which often cause very visible "crushing" injuries). Whereas they probably *should* worry more about the deep punctures from (sharper) cat teeth. But I only posted my comment by way of "interesting snippet", not to start or prolong a dick-measuring contest.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Tut-tut, now. There's a way to be a gracious loser, and a way to be a dork. I'll let you figure out which one you are.

Comment: If I didn't know better, judging by the number of *mordant* comments between them, I'd say FF and medica have a thing for each other... As for the edit, *dragon's mouth*? *Dragon's mouth* is one of the most absurd edits I have witnessed in a long time. I can't think of any animal whose bite might not create an infection in a human, but at least a dog doesn't come from a fairytale.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - for crying out loud, if you don't like the edit, just change it! I just don't like medical misinformation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I swore I wouldn't add anything more to this thread, but I assume medica is referring to the dragons of Pern, an extraterrestrial species.  (Dragons of Pern, by Anne McCaffrey.)   Because their genetic material is probably completely different,  an extraterrestrial species would be unlikely to infect humans or any other terrestrial species.  This is my last post on this topic, no matter what, cross my heart.

Comment: *snort* *snort* :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **pathogen** *- any disease-producing agent, especially a virus, bacterium, or other microorganism* <sub><sup>([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pathogen))</sup></sub>
>
> **pathogenic** *- capable of producing disease* <sub><sup>([thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pathogenic))</sup></sub>

And [an example usage](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QcEbBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22pathogenic%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22pathogenic%20to%22&f=false) approximating OP's context...

> *Seventeen different species of Yersinia genus have so far been reported, of which three have been shown to be **pathogenic to humans** and animals.*

Answer (score 6):

You might be thinking of ***susceptible*** and it is a term used in virology also.

> with *of* or *to*: Capable of being physically affected by; esp. liable to take, subject to (a disease or other affection). *[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195121?redirectedFrom=susceptible#eid)*

However, it is usually used as *susceptible to < disease name/cause >* thus you have to turn your sentences around.

> ...mosquitoes are not susceptible to those germs.

Here is an example from a scientific publication:

> Such a mechanism is urgently needed by those working to reduce the impact of malaria by releasing strains of **Anopheles, the vector of the disease, that are not susceptible to malaria parasites.**
>
> <sub>*http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11527447*</sub>

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Comment: But you have to turn the sentence around and say, “mosquitos are not susceptible to those germs’.

Comment: @Jim: Yes I mentioned that. OP might be thinking the other way around because he doesn't remember the word exactly. I read the question as the virus can affect *certain* species.

Comment: @Jim: I made it more clear now. OP could clarify the question a bit further but I strongly believe that he meant this.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for ***[infectious](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=W0lfj9TkQUMC&pg=PT15&dq=%22infectious%20to%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAmoVChMI0uSN9vnlxgIVwSGmCh2KyAcF#v=onepage&q=%22infectious%20to%22&f=false) :***

> - Capable of causing infection: an infectious microorganism.
> - Capable of being transmitted by infection: an infectious disease.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=infectious%20to%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinfectious%20to%3B%2Cc0): *infectious to*

- We have restricted ourselves to agents ***infectious to humans***: strictly animal and plant pathogens are not addressed, although many of the practices recommended here are useful in the prevention of their spread. We deal only briefly with the ...[Biosafety in the Laboratory::](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=W0lfj9TkQUMC&pg=PT15&dq=%22infectious%20to%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAmoVChMI0uSN9vnlxgIVwSGmCh2KyAcF#v=onepage&q=%22infectious%20to%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for might be **toxic**

-containing or being poisonous material especially when capable of causing          death or serious debilitation

-extremely harsh, malicious, or harmful

1.Mosquitoes don't die of the diseases they transmit because those germs are not ***toxic*** to mosquitoes

2.Dog's mouths aren't really clean, but they're generally not harmful to humans because the germs in a dog's mouth are not ***toxic*** to humans

Answer (score -1):

Another term, although it may not be the one you're looking for, is phage. Examples are bacteria- phage, or animal- phage. It means something that devours. Phages are very host- specific. Other than that, the answer of "infectious" from josh61 is a good one.

Answer (score -2):

### Contagious

If a virus (or what not) is [capable of being easily spread to others](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contagious), then it is a **contagion**

and contagions are *contagious*

Not just viruses, diseases, or other malevolent things either.

Happiness, laughter, cheerfulness, et al can be *contagious* as well.

Comment: But you can’t say, “... because those germs aren’t *contagious* to mosquitos.”

Comment: Yes you can. http://www.ijamscr.com/sites/default/files/articles/IJAMSCR-15-103%20Tripathi.pdf

Comment: -1: But the germs ***are*** contagious to mosquitos; they're just not harmful to mosquitos. This is not the word the OP wants.